# Updated Controller not taking effect Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that was created in another version of visual studio, however I have opened it in vs 2017. While the program maybe executing if I make any changes to a controller, nothing happens only revert to the old version of the project. I have done some research saw where they deleted the generated files form the framework, but still the changes doesn't seem to take effect. i don't what the problem what the issue :(

**Applicationhost.config**

```
<sites>
        <!-- <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site> -->
        <site name="com.twcl.it.isms" id="1">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TWCLIssuingManagementSystem" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up a command line prompt and enter this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
appcmd list site
```

Find you website name, and then enter this:

```
appcmd delete site YourWebsiteName
```

It should clear the IIS cache for that site. Good luck.

Comment: SITE "WebSite1" (id:1,bindings:http/:8080:localhost,state:Unknown) the results I get

Comment: the website is stored in wwwroot folder

Comment: Run this then: appcmd delete site WebSite1

Comment: SITE object "WebSite1" deleted but that isn't the name of website

Comment: Delete these files then:
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version_Num\ComponentModelCache
If this helps you, please mark as answer

Comment: there are no files there

Comment: The last thing i would try is check your iis config file and search for your site name. Make sure it is pointing to the correct directory.
%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config

Comment: the generated files are store in framework64 and framework

Comment: it doesn't have the site name

Comment: I have edited the question with what I have in applicationhost.config should I change something else

Comment: I have made all the changes and I still don't see the effect on the controller

Comment: still figured out the issue as yet. Would it because of the files in bin and obj, although when I delete them I'm getting errors. Can you assist me please? :(

Comment: I am fairly certain it is an HRESULT:0xID10T error. Search for this visual studio error and you should find your answer.

Comment: so where do I find that? :(